# How to add a UIActivityIndicatorView inside a AlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like to show an alertview saying the process is in progress and would like to add the UIActivityIndicatorView inside the alertview to show the process is in progress, instead of outside the alertview. How do I do that? Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: just use addSubview method

Comment: found an example on that... posted it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" "Process in Progress..." " ];
UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[alert addSubview:progress];
[progress startAnimating];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Since you have no buttons on your `UIAlertView`, there is no need to set its `delegate` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to use [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

and if u need to show some image and text then, [use this](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast)